# Ubuntu 14.04 installer insists on running in UEFI mode

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-7, uefi

I am trying to dual boot Windows 7 along side Ubuntu 14.04. I have managed to set this up successfully on my old laptop (which only uses Legacy BIOS) using an installation CD and EasyBCD. However when I go to set it up on my newer laptop it insists on running the Ubuntu installer in EUFI mode.

The newer laptop has just had windows 7 installed onto it with the BIOS set to Legacy mode,
when insert the CD and tell the new laptop to boot from that it insists on booting the installer in EUFI mode. (The older laptop was able to run the ubuntu installer fine in Legacy mode.)

If I understand correctly both OS need to be installed in the same mode. My preference would be to use legacy mode as this is the default setting for my laptop and will work with EasyBCD.

I tried installing windows 7 in EUFI mode but the installer couldn't boot properly.

Is it possible to force my laptop to boot the installer using Legacy mode?

Comment: Most EFIs that support both modes provide two options to boot external media in the computer's built-in boot manager. One option includes the string "UEFI" and boots in that mode. The other option lacks that string and boots in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. Try entering your boot manager (typically by pressing a function key at startup -- but which one varies from one machine to another) and see if there are two such options. If so, pick the right one.

Answer (score -1):

How to get your laptop to boot the cd in bios mode is specific to your model of laptop: you will have to read the manual or contact the manufacturer about that.  However, when installing Ubuntu along side an existing bios booting Windows install, it will automatically stick with bios booting even though the installer itself is booted in UEFI mode.

Comment: so even if it boots the installer in UEFI mode it should still boot the resulting OS in Legacy mode?

Comment: @user262751, yes, provided that you choose to install along side an existing bios booting windows.